# Add json inside json in Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write in a json file a specific string. My code for doing so is the following:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
client = MongoClient()
client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
db = client['my_db_values']
collection = db['db_values']

json_file = {"User": "2145", "Item": {"123456": {}}}
temp_json1 = {"timestamp": "2123532158", "process1_value": 0.4, "state": {"B": 0.1, "F": 0.2, "E": 0.3}}
temp_json2 = {"timestamp": "2323532158", "process2_value": 0.2, "P": 0.8}
json_file ["Item"][str(123456)]["process1"].append(temp_json1)
json_file ["Item"][str(123456)]["process2"].append(temp_json2)
```

Actually I have created the json file "json_file" and I want to add the sub-json for the process1 and process 2 which will be sub-categories of the "Item" field. My code does not work as I want and I am receiving the following error:

> ```
> json_file ["Item"][str(213546879213)]["process1"].append(temp_json1)
> ```
>
> TypeError: 'set' object has no attribute '**getitem**'

My json want to look like:

```
{
"User": "213546879546213",
"Item": {
    "213546879": {
        "Process1": [{
            "Timestamp": "213546879213",
            "Process1_Value": 0.4,
            "state": {
                "B": 0.2,
                "F": 0.8,
                "E": 0.1

            }
        }],
        "Sla_Weight_Personalization": [{
            "Timestamp": "213546879",
            "Process2_Value": 0.4,
            "P": 0.8
        }]
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: `{"123456"}` that's a set. You probably want to use something else, here.

Comment: Sup dawg, I heard you like JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the line

```
json_file = {"User": "2145", "Item": {"123456"}}
```

... you are creating the Item entry as the `set` `{"123456"}` containing a single entry, but you must initialize it as a `dict`. You probably want to initialize it as `{"123456": {}}` or `{}` (an empty dict) instead.

Note that Python syntax on dict and set literals can be a bit confusing: `{x}` is a set, `{x: y}` is a dict, and `{}` is an empty dict (use `set()` for the empty set).

---

In order for the two `append` lines last in your code to work, you need to initialize the `"123456"` to be a dict containing empty `"process1"` and `"process2"` lists, as follows:

```
json_file = {
    "User": "2145",
    "Item": {
        "123456": {
            "process1": [],
            "process2": [],
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: This valus it is a id of the item i just want to have a lot of values with a sub-list inside with properties.

Comment: Using the syntax `{"123456"}` in the context of JSON is definitely wrong, since `{"123456"}` is not valid JSON. Use `{"123456": {}}` instead or something similar that's appropriate for your use-case.

Comment: So sth like that json_file = {"User": "2145", "Item": {"123456": {}}}?

Comment: Well, try it out and let me know if it works. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: Tried json_file = {"User": "2145", "Item": {"123456": {}}} and I got KeyError: 'process1' from the line ->json_file ["Item"][str(123456)]["process1"].append(temp_json1)

Comment: Beatiful! Thanks for the answer!